# Conseguir todas las probabilidades de que las personas que votaron por el partido Pᵢ en 2008 voten por el partido Pᵣ en 2013 con regresión lineal

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, regresión-lineal

Tengo un conjunto de datos de los precintos y los resultados de los partidos sobre las diferentes elecciones (centrémonos en dos: 2008,2013). Después de leer [este artículo](https://towardsdatascience.com/analysing-belgian-election-results-5c4124452689) realmente quería usar la regresión lineal para responder a la pregunta: ¿cómo cambiaron los votantes de opinión desde las últimas elecciones?

```
Unnamed: 0  Map Level   Precinct ID Precinct Name   Election    Invalid Ballots (%) More Ballots Than Votes (#) More Votes Than Ballots (#) Total Voter Turnout (#) Total Voter Turnout (%) ... Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)  CDM ED  FG  GD  LP  NR  UNM Results others
0   0   Precinct    1   63-1    2008 Parliamentary  0.0 0.0 0.0 749 62.11   ... 1.01    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 77.17   United National Movement    22.83
1   1   Precinct    10  63-10   2008 Parliamentary  0.0 0.0 0.0 419 70.42   ... 0.61    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 71.12   United National Movement    28.87
...
136 159 Precinct    8   63-1    2013 Presidential   1.75    0.0 0.0 506 50.75   ... 0.52    2.96    0.20    0.00    0.00    1.19    0.00    0.00    Giorgi Margvelashvili   95.65
137 160 Precinct    9   63-10   2013 Presidential   2.50    0.0 0.0 625 48.04   ... 0.66    1.92    0.80    0.00    0.00    1.60    0.00    0.00    Giorgi Margvelashvili   95.68
```

Donde un precinto dado se proporciona en `Precinct Name`.

Para entender qué votantes cambiaron de opinión se puede construir un modelo muy simple.
Usted puede simplificar las elecciones a un sistema de partidos N, eliminando todos los partidos que no sean de su interés (u obtuvieron menos de una cantidad de votos tanto en la primera como en la segunda elección).
Entonces, si se asume que todas las personas que votaron de manera similar en 2014, cambiarán de opinión de la misma manera en 2019. Más específicamente, las personas que votaron por el partido Pᵢ en 2008, tienen la misma probabilidad de votar por el partido Pᵣ en 2013. (A esta probabilidad la llamo Xᵢᵣ)

Por lo tanto, para un precinto dado con el fin de "explicar" o "predecir" el número de votos Vᵣ²⁰¹⁹ para el partido Pᵣ en 2013, sobre la base de los resultados de 2008 puedo utilizar las probabilidades Xᵢᵣ de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Es una simple regresión lineal. Así que, en la medida en que tengamos 7 partes el resultado debería ser para cada Xᵢᵣ una matriz de tamaño 7. Sin embargo. Con el modelo de regresión lineal que estoy mostrando justo después, no es el caso.

Así que intenté implementar el modelo en Python

```
def error(x_i,y_i, beta):
    return y_i - predict(x_i, beta)

def squared_error(x_i, y_i, beta):
    return error(x_i, y_i, beta)**2

def squared_error_gradient(x_i, y_i, beta):
    """the gradient (with respect to beta)
    corresponding to the ith squared error term"""
    return [-2 * x_ij * error(x_i,y_i, beta)
           for x_ij in x_i]

def predict(x_i, beta):
    # x_i.insert(0,1)
    """assumes that the first element of each x_i is 1"""
    return dot(x_i, beta)

def dot(v, w):
    """v_1 * w_1 + ... + v_n * w_n"""
    return sum(v_i * w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w))

def in_random_order(data):
    """generator that returns the elements of data in random order"""
    indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)] # create a list of indexes
    random.shuffle(indexes) # shuffle them
    for i in indexes: # return the data in that order
        yield data[i]

def minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x, y, theta_0, alpha_0=0.01):
    data = zip(x, y)
    theta = theta_0 # initial guess
    alpha = alpha_0 # initial step size
    min_theta, min_value = None, float("inf") # the minimum so far
    iterations_with_no_improvement = 0

    # if we ever go 100 iterations with no improvement, stop
    while iterations_with_no_improvement < 100:
        value = sum( target_fn(x_i, y_i, theta) for x_i, y_i in data )
        if value < min_value:
            # if we've found a new minimum, remember it
            # and go back to the original step size
            min_theta, min_value = theta, value
            iterations_with_no_improvement = 0
            alpha = alpha_0
        else:
            # otherwise we're not improving, so try shrinking the step size
            iterations_with_no_improvement += 1
            alpha *= 0.9
            # and take a gradient step for each of the data points
        for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
            gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
            theta = vector_subtract(theta, scalar_multiply(alpha, gradient_i))
    return min_theta

def estimate_beta(x,y):
    beta_initial = [random.random() for x_i in x[0]]
    return minimize_stochastic(squared_error,
                              squared_error_gradient,
                              x,y,
                              beta_initial,
                              0.001)
```

Por ejemplo, digamos que tenemos la eleccion en 2008 y una en 2013:

```
x = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [77.17], [22.83]] # cada arreglo dentro de este arreglo es el % de personas que votaron por un partido en 2008
y = [[0.35], [0.35], [0.0], [0.0], [2.43], [0.0], [0.0], [96.87]] # cada número es el % de personas que votaron por un partido en 2013
random.seed(0)
random.seed(0)
probabilities = [estimate_beta(x,y_i)for y_i in y]
print(probabilities)
```

Me devuelve :

```
[[0.8444218515250481], [0.7579544029403025], [0.420571580830845], [0.25891675029296335], [0.5112747213686085], [0.4049341374504143], [0.7837985890347726], [0.30331272607892745]]
```

Esperaba un número de valores igual al número de partidos en cada arregla.

Comment: Tengo una duda: SO esta orientado a corregir problemas de la implementación de un código, y considerando que el wiki de *machine-learning* no describe sobre las limitaciones del uso de esa etiqueta aun tengo duda si tu pregunta es válida ya que tu pregunta no es acerca del código sino sobre la válidez de tu formula,

Comment: [cont.] entonces reviso la wiki de SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info y veo: *NOTE: If you want to use this tag for a question not directly concerning implementation, then consider posting on Computer Science, Cross Validated or Data Science instead. Otherwise you're probably off-topic.* Que claramente indica que en ese sitio no seria valido tu pregunta, ¿Se puede extrapolar lo mismo en SOes?

Comment: @eyllanesc Gracias por su comentario. Reconsideraré la pregunta. Mi pregunta es más sobre la implementación, ya que no tengo tantos resultados como pensé que podría tener para dibujar la heat map.

Comment: He editado la wiki de la etiqueta para evitar futuras confusiones, aunque aun esta en la cola de revisión.

Comment: yo pienso que tu pregunta no es de implemetación sino de modelamiento

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es una pregunta de programación sino de modelamiento